# Make blue glass shader in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I would like to make a blue glass shader in cycles.
Something like this:
[image]

This was my first trying but I think it's terrible.
[image: just glass shader]

And here's my second trying but it doesn't look well.
[image: mix shader]

Is there any way to make a shader like on the first image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to **mix** **two *Glass Shaders***- one with a white color and the other with a blueish color. Set the mix factor to a low value to make glass look more blueish and transparent at the same time. With a good lighting setup you'll achieve the effect you want.

[image]